# Counting current user's hyperlink clicks with JavaScript, localStorage and Php

Tags: javascript, php, html, local-storage, counter

I am trying to record the number of clicks performed by a user on the hyperlinks of a web page using `localStorage`. I am having issues displaying/refreshing click count right after users click on hyperlinks.

Any ideas where/what i'm doing wrong, here is the code i use:

```php
<?php
echo "Name: ". $row["user"] . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5).
'<a href="'.$row['lin'].' onClick= "Click();" ">Click</a>';
?>
```

below is the js function being called:

```js
function Click() {
    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (localStorage.clickcount) {
            localStorage.clickcount = Number(localStorage.clickcount)+1;
        } else {
            localStorage.clickcount = 1;
        }

        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "You have clicked " + localStorage.clickcount + " time(s).";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Sorry, your browser does not support web storage...";
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: As far as I can see, your string isn't properly formatted, particularly this part: `'<a href="'.$row['lin'].' onClick= "Click();" ">Click</a>'`. This would output the the HTML element as `<a href="http://some.link onClick="Click();"">Click</a>`, so the `onclick` attribute isn't properly set and won't be called. Your end quotation mark is in the wrong place, try to format your string like this: `echo "Name: ". $row["user"] . str_repeat('&nbsp;', 5). '<a href="'.$row['lin'].'" onClick="Click();">Click</a>';`

Comment: It might be better to omit the inline event handler `Click` and instead assign a either a delegated event listener on the document or create a nodelist collection and assign a click handler to each member

Comment: When the user clicks on a link they will be transported to that link so they should not see the number of times they have clicked a particular link. If you set the `target` attribute - ie: `target="_new"` ) the link will be followed in a new tab/window and the clickcount will still be visible in the original window. If however you wish to record for all users then `localStorage` is not a suitable choice